# CSS3 site won't work in IE. Even IE10

Tags: internet-explorer, css

So I've got this problem that I made a site in css3 and it kind of works for me - when I click the left button, it goes left. The right button makes it go right. Works perfect in Firefox, not so perfect in chrome but I think I'll be able to fix that myself as the buttons do their job, but IE totally ignores the buttons (which are labels to be exact).

The code is pretty long, so maybe it would be better to give you the link:
http://gametabloid.com/thinkone

The code is a little bit messy and works only up to 1440px in width so if your screen is larger please resize the browser. Apologies for that.

What I ask for is a solution for IE. I tried to keep it in CSS since I don't know JavaScript, but now I'm desperate. Any solution would do - JS, CSS, Wordpress theme even. Please help.

The basic idea was that I made a div with overflow: hidden; and put a table inside with three cells, each of the size of the div. When we visit the site, the middle cell is visible. Outside of the table there are two checkboxes (not visible), but I put the labels inside - they change the position of the whole table.

Comment: You'll be better off to isolate the relevant snippets of code and paste them here. Also, a http://jsfiddle.net/ would help out a lot.

Comment: I tried that but the page looked a whole lot different for some reason :(

Comment: You are specifying HTML 3.1 in your DOCTYPE. Use a HTML 5 DOCTYPE

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It might have something to do with this: `<!doctype html public "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">`

Try changing it to this: `<!DOCTYPE html>`

You might want to start off with something like this: http://html5boilerplate.com/

Comment: It did not help but I gave me a direction. I'll try to clean the code and then repost. Thanks!